# Is It Possible To BatchGet Multiple Items By Partition Key Only DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have items with ItemID's and Paths. ItemID is the partition key and Path is the range key. If I have multiple ItemID's I want to query, but don't want to include the range key is it possible to do it with `batchGet` or will I have to use `query` for each of the ItemID's? I have tried `batchGet` but get the error `"The provided key element does not match the schema"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get the items based on Partition key only. The **batch get item API** requires both Partition and Range key.

> Keys - An array of primary key attribute values that define specific
>   items in the table. For each primary key, you must provide all of the
>   key attributes. For example, with a simple primary key, you only need
>   to provide the partition key value. For a composite key, you must
>   provide both the partition key value and the sort key value.

However, you can use **Query API** to get the data by partition key only.